# Cannot find how many vowels are in a given text using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Well, our country's alphabet has " o' " vowel as well (Uzbek_alphabet).

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzbek_alphabet

So, I have been trying to find how many vowels are in a given text using Javascript. But, one word is not working " o' ". I don't know what to do now.

```js
let text = "O'afiuoooefmanbqo'"
    console.log(text)
    text = text.toLocaleLowerCase()
    let count = 0
    let count2 = 0
    let count3 = 0
    let count4 = 0
    let count5 = 0
    let count6 = 0

    for (let i of text) {

        if (i === "a") {

            count++
        } else if (i === "e") {

            count2++
        } else if (i === "i") {

            count3++
        } else if (i === "o") {

            count4++
        } else if (i === "u") {

            count5++
        } else if (i === "o'") {

            count6++
        }
    }
    console.log(count + "  'a'  vowels")
    console.log(count2 + " 'e'  vowels")
    console.log(count3 + " 'i'  vowels")
    console.log(count4 + " 'o'  vowels")
    console.log(count5 + " 'u'  vowels")
    console.log(count6 + " 'o'' vowels")
```

Comment: `o'` is not read as a single char.

Comment: which country's alphabet are we talking about? or Language :)

Comment: Uzbekistan, uzbek language. There are also some other words ( o' , g' , ' ) in uzbek alphabet.  " o' " is vowel , " g' " is consonant.

Comment: Does this character have a separate unicode value or are you looking to check the `o'` combination? if the latter then you need to check next character if you come across `o`..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because first "o" is read as a character from the text, and after "'" is read as character from the text.

Maybe, add the following a case:

```
prev_char = ""; //empty initialisation

for i in text {
//other if statements

else if (i === "'") {
   if ( prev_char === "o") {
      count6++; // increase counter o'
      count4--; // decrease counter o that was upped during previous character call
   }

}

prev_char = i
}
```

I do not write javascript often, so the syntax might be off, but something like this might work.

In this case you should also still remove the counter from the o vowel, so count4--

Comment: There are also some other words ( o' , g' , ' ) in uzbek alphabet.  " o' " is vowel , " g' " is consonant.

Comment: yes, but you also check the letter before with the code I posted. So you first check, did I encounter ', then, was the letter before an o? In that case, increase the counter

Answer (score 0):

I will do that this way :

```js
console.log( UzbekVowelsCounts( "O'afiuoooefmanbqo'" ))

function UzbekVowelsCounts ( txt )
  {
  const count = 
    { 'a'  : 0
    , 'e'  : 0
    , 'i'  : 0
    , 'o'  : 0
    , 'u'  : 0
    , 'oʻ' : 0
    , sum  : 0 
    }

  txt = txt.toLocaleLowerCase()

  for (let i = 0; i<txt.length; i++)
    {
    let letter = txt[i]
    if (count[letter] != undefined )
      {
      count.sum++
      if ( letter === 'o' 
       && i < txt.length 
       &&  "'ʻ".includes(txt[i+1]) 
       )
        {
        count['oʻ']++
        i++
        }
      else 
        count[letter]++
      }
    }
  return count
  }
```

in a compact code :

```js
console.log( UzbekVowelsCounts( "O'afiuoooefmanbqo'" ))

function UzbekVowelsCounts ( txt )
  {
  return [...txt.toLocaleLowerCase()].reduce((counts,L,i,{[i+1]:L2}) =>
    {
    if (counts[L] != undefined )
      {
      counts.sum++
      if ("'ʻ".includes(L2) && L==='o' ) counts['oʻ']++
      else                               counts[L]++
      }
    return counts
    }, {'a':0,'e':0,'i':0,'o':0,'u':0,'oʻ':0,sum:0})
  }
```